# How do I fix errors 2298 and 2563

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a class for an assignment. It is supposed to record how long it takes a program to run and how many times a loop is looped and then put that information into a file. Right now, it is giving me:

```
error 2298 "missing call to bound pointer to member function"
```

and

```
error 2563 "mismatch in formal parameter list."
```

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to fix these; it's probably less complicated than I'm making it, but any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Timer {
  private:
    typedef chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
    Clock::time_point epoch;
  public:
    Timer() {
        epoch = Clock::now();
    }
    Clock::duration getElapsedTime() { return Clock::now() - epoch; }
};

int loopCount()
{
    for (int count=0;count<=100;) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int fProjectDebugFile() 
{
    fstream debugFile;

    debugFile.open ("FinalProjectDebugger.txt", fstream::out | fstream::app);
    string jar(Timer);
    cout << jar << endl << loopCount() << endl;
    debugFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this all of the code you have?

Comment: While the code you posted triggers compiler errors, it does not trigger either of the two error messages you listed? This code has problems resolving `count` and a warning that the function pointer `jar` will never be null, but it has no pointer-to-member function.

Comment: @JaMiT, `jar` is a `string` not a function pointer.  Also, what kind of error messages you get depend on which compiler/linker you use.

Comment: @SidS No, `jar` is declared as a function that takes a `Timer` parameter and returns a `string`. (gcc: *"the address of 'std::string jar(Timer)' will never be NULL";* clang: *address of function 'jar' will always evaluate to 'true'*.) Which compiler gave you a warning or error that mentioned a pointer-to-member function?

Comment: @JaMiT, Yes I see what you meant now.  `string jar(Timer);` declares a function that takes a `Timer` object as a parameter and returns a `string`.

Comment: @JaMiT, Also, my compiler didn't mention anything about pointer-to-member.  You probably have me confused with the one that asked the question.

Comment: @SidS No, I asked you that because you stated that the kind of error messages depends on which compiler I use. That is true, but a theoretical possibility is weak. To convince me that the question is on-topic (and warrants an answer), I would like to know which compiler actually produces error messages close to those from the question.

Comment: @JaMiT I used CLion to write the code, here's a link to a screenshot https://imgur.com/a/wfsJ7XL

Comment: @BLARG CLion is your IDE. It looks like your compiler is MSVC? Both errors appear to refer to your attempt to return `count`, assuming the code scrolled off the top of the image matches the code in the question. It's still strange that MSVC sees a pointer-to-member in that context, but then again, it is MS. (Both gcc and clang describe `count` as an "overloaded function".) In any event, you would probably get a more applicable error message if you dropped the line `using namespace std;` and added the `std::` prefix where needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access loop variables outside the loop.

So, move the declaration outside the loop, i.e. replace this :

```
int loopCount(){
    for(int count=0;count<=100;){
         count++;}
return count;
}
```

with this:

```
int loopCount()
{
    int count = 0;
    while (count <= 100)
    {
         count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

---

Also, this :

```
class Timer
...
string jar(Timer);
```

doesn't make much sense.  `Timer` is a type, so `string jar(Timer);` declares a function named `jar` that takes a `Timer` object as a parameter and returns a `string`.

Comment: The edit was the ticket. Your first cut was right, but there was more that prompted the specific errors. The edit got it.